# How to get only zipcode in address using angular5

Tags: angular

I have an address like this

```
address = "1a, Hitech City Rd, Sri Sai Nagar, Madhapur, Hyderabad, Telangana 500081, India"
```

Here i need only zipcode, I tried like this

```
ngOnInit(){
var y=this.address.split(",")
this.z=y[5]
this.addr=this.z.split(" ")[2]
}
```

and this is working, but address is not exactly same to all locations. I modified like this

```
address = "1a, Hitech City Rd, Sri Sai Nagar, Madhapur, Hyderabad,500081, India,Streetno:123"
```

in the above address then the above logic will not work. Is there any other way to get only zipcode.
Please help.

Comment: I have given a code snippet below, run it and let me know the results!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: you can place pin/zip code anywhere in the text.

```
 let address = "1a, Hitech City Rd, Sri Sai Nagar,500081, Madhapur, Hyderabad, Telangana, India";

 let res = address.split(",").map(data => data
  .trim()
  .match("\\d{6}"))
  .filter(filtered => filtered)[0][0];

 console.log(res);
```

Hope this would help you! :)

Comment: This won't match the first example though because after the split on the `,` you get `Telangana 500081`.  The `trim()` won't take away the "Telangana" portion.

Comment: Please execute this code snippet and inform me... @TylerMarshall, as it is working for me. :)

Comment: Oh, you're right!  Although, since you're using the `match()`, do you need the `trim()` anymore?  The regex should ignore any whitespace around the fields.

Answer (score 0):

Zip codes are always the same length, format, and are always numeric. This is a perfect fit for a REGEX. Here's your regex

```
[0-9]{6,6}
```

This will match all 6 digit sequences. You will need to handle the edge case of having an address number which is six digits. In that case, though, you know you'll always want the second set since address numbers will always come before the zip code.